# postgres select all dates from interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to with Postgres I Could retrieve all dates using parameters 'from' and 'until'

example:

```
select date from 'maybe a system table' where date >= :from and date <= :to
```

then te result is for (02-01-2015 and 05-01-2015)

```
 date
 ------------
 02-01-2015
 03-01-2015
 04-01-2015
 05-01-2015
```

What is the Best way to do this with Postgres, I know how to do with Oracle, but I need change my Database?? I Want to do a join with a table that does not have register with all dates and my report needs all days in one days interval

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `generate_series()`.  Here is an example for the days in January, 2015:

```
select generate_series('2015-01-01'::timestamp, '2015-01-31'::timestamp,
                       '1 day')::date
```

Comment: thanks Gordon, works excellent. I added a Cross Join with generate_series to Retrieve records for all dates.